# Posting messages to different interfaces on ROS2

Tags: ros2

I have 2 Ethernet ports and 10 topics. Is it possible to publish topics 1 3 5 7 9 on 1 port, and the remaining topics 2 2 6 6 10 to publish on port 2 so that a computer connected to the second port can only see and read data from topics 2 4 6 8 10. A computer connected to port 1 could see and read data from topics 1 3 5 7 9. I use DDS from OpenSplice.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to configure the following flag:

```
 <NetworkInterfaceAddress>AUTO</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
```

In chapter "5.4  Configuration", from the Getting started Documentation: http://download.prismtech.com/docs/Vortex/pdfs/OpenSplice_GettingStartedGuide.pdf
you can get more details about the configuration of the OpenSlice DDS and what parameters you can specify.

In the RMW specific to Openslice, it seems to use the default QoS configuration:
https://github.com/ros2/rmw_opensplice/blob/6a767545270ae56c0894cfb0286509add3ca7c2b/rmw_opensplice_cpp/src/rmw_publisher.cpp#L113

Which should make use of the default configuration file: ospl.xml

You can either update the RMW to use another QoS that will comply to your needs, or use the OSPL_URI before launching your publisher to update the QoS of your publishers.